# How can I make plot values into callable floats?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to write a script based on the Ichimoku indicator and use the Lagging Span plot:

`plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")`

into a condition like:

`laggingSpan = plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#43A047, title="Lagging Span")

if laggingSpan > high
...`

I tried just that and I was getting this error: "Error at 34:76 Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr0'='laggingSpan'. An argument of 'plot' type was used but a 'simple float' is expected."

and then I tried

`laggingSpan = close[-displacement + 1]`

but I'm getting this error:

> Invalid number of bars back [-25] within the history-referencing operator. The value must be >= 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea with `laggingSpan = close[-displacement + 1]` is right but you need to understand how the Ichimoku Cloud works.

The lagging span is the current price moved x-bars (typically 26) back in time. So, you see, the only way to know its value on a given bar is to know the future price. Don't we all want to know that?

But you can do the same thing you did for the leading span A and B. That will work.

```
leadingSpanA = leadLine1[displacement - 1]
```

Comment: Dang, I didn't think of it like that.. Would be pretty nice if it worked lol. Thanks for clearing it up!